# Pegar array de json no ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Boa tarde, estou com um problema pra exibir o resultado no json, eu faço um insert de um array no banco de dados com for, ele insere perfeito no banco de dados, mas não to conseguindo exibir no json a resposta de sucesso. Meu ajax está assim:

```
var recuperarResultado = function(){

    $('.btnCadastrarMensa').on('click', function(e){
    event.preventDefault();

         var form = $('#formMen').serialize();

         $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url:'admin/mensal',
           data: form,
           dataType: "JSON",
               success: function(res){

                       var div_concluido = '<div class="row margin-top-40">'+
                                            '<div class="col-md-12 text-center">'+
                                               '<h2>' + res.msg + '</h2>'+
                                                '</div>'+  
                                          '</div>';          
                               $('.mensalidade_concluido').removeClass('d-none');
                               $('.mensalidade_concluido').html(div_concluido);           

            },error: function(res){

                  console.log(res);                       
             }
         });
    });
}
```

Minha função de inserção no banco está assim:

```
//Cadastrar Mensa dos Clientes
  public function mensal(){

     if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $retorno = '';

        //puxo a lista dos dados do cliente
        $cliente = $this->mensa_model->listarClientes();

     //coloco ele em um array
         $cliente = array_map(function($item){

            return $item->{'id'};

            },$cliente);

            echo"<pre>";
            print_r($cliente);

        //insiro os dados um por um com o for   
        $contador = count($cliente);
        for($i=0; $i < $contador; $i++){

            $mensa['id_cliente'] = $cliente[$i];
            $mensa['dt_mensal'] = $this->input->post('datas');
            $mensa['status'] = "1";
            $query = $this->mensa_model->doInsertMensa($mensa);
        }


     //E aqui exibo a mensagem de sucesso

          $retorno = [
            'erro' => 0,
            'msg' => 'Sucesso'
        ];



    }  else {

          $retorno = [
              'erro' => 10,
              'msg' => 'Erro ao inserir dados'
          ];
      }       

      echo json_encode($retorno);    
   }
```

No resultado do console em response ele vem mostrando que foi inserido com sucesso:

```
responseText: "<pre>Array↵(↵    [0] => 1↵    [1] => 3↵    [2] => 4↵    [3] => 6↵    [4] => 7↵    [5] => 8↵    [6] => 9↵)↵{"erro":0,"msg":"Sucesso"}
```

Ou seja ele inseri no banco tudo certinho, mas não consigo exibir a resposta de sucesso, ele passa direto e vai pra erro mostrando a mensagem de erro.. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: coloca o codigo do método em php que retorna a resposta

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual já atualizei e acrescentei o método, mas está tudo perfeito, só a resposta no ajax que não exibe

Comment: Pelo menos no trecho de código que você postou, está faltando as aspas da _string_ passada pro campo `url` e está faltando uma vírgula depois do campo `dataType`.

Comment: @Gustavo Sampaio, sim já arrumei, e continua com o mesmo problema, ele não exibe a resposta de sucesso, só no console

Comment: Na verdade, o que está acontecendo é que você está misturando JSON com HTML. E você pede pro AJAX converter a resposta da requisição para JSON, sendo que a resposta trouxe um conteúdo misturado. Portanto, ele gera um erro, já que `<pre>...` não é algo que deveria estar presente em um arquivo JSON. Portanto, tente colocar o conteúdo HTML dentro do objeto JSON, ao invés de usar o `echo` e o `print_r`.

Comment: @Gustavo Sampaio Resolvi já. eu estava usando o trecho do código: echo"<pre>";
            print_r($cliente); pra ver o resultado no response, eu tirei funcionou perfetito..Obrigado a tds pela ajuda

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

2 problemas!

1) Você não está retornando JSON puro!

```
echo"<pre>";
print_r($cliente);
```

2) O Javascript precisa transformar o JSON em objeto!

```
success: function(retorno){

   var res = JSON.parse(retorno); // CONVERTE JSON EM OBJETO

   // res.erro e res.msg ficarão acessíveis
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado meu amigo pela ajuda.

Comment: DICA: use e abuse do Console... console.log('Retorno AJAX: ' + retorno) , ai você consegue identificar possíveis falhas ;)

Comment: mto obrigao, eu ainda sou meio iniciante, mas to pegando o jeito kkk, valew pelas dicas irmão